# Basic plot using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, rstudio, data-visualization

I have a data frame **t1** as follows:

```
   V1    V2
1  1 83.60687
2  2 83.90725
3  3 84.03346
4  4 85.89171
```

I want to plot V2 vs V1 by using ggplot but unable to do it:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = t1, aes(x = V1, y = V2)) + 
geom_point()
```

It gives me an error saying:

**Error in readRDS(nsInfoFilePath) : error reading from connection
In addition: Warning message:
In readRDS(nsInfoFilePath) : error reading the file**

How can I plot my data points? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A package has been corrupted - see https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/R-3-3-0-Crashing-Error-in-readRDS-nsInfoFilePath-unknown-input-format-td4720766.html - try re-installing ggplot2

Comment: I re-installed it but no luck.

Comment: might be a package that ggplot2 is using - there are many of these. If you are not on the latest version of R, this would be a good time to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

The following works correctly -- I suspect you have a problem unrelated to plotting.

```
V1 = c(1,2,3,4)
V2 = c(83,84,85,86)

t1=data.frame(V1,V2)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = t1, aes(x = V1, y = V2)) + 
  geom_point()
```

Comment: I believe I have a corrupted package. I tried using using your code but still it gives me the same error.